# React: How to use arrow up/down to select previous/next item in a scroll list and make the list scroll to keep the selected element on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web-deployment

I'm using react-infinite scroll list and i'm implemented an arrow up/down handler:

```
onKeyDown = (e) => {
    if(e.keyCode === 40){
        if (this.props.onKeyDown) {
            e.preventDefault()
            this.props.onKeyDown()
        }
    }
    else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        if (this.props.onKeyUp) {
            e.preventDefault()
            this.props.onKeyUp()
        }
    }
}
```

(The component is reusable throughout my application so I pass the actual functions through props)

This works as far as selecting the next/previous item in the list. But when you reach the edge of the scroll list and keep going, the list doesn't scroll to keep the selected item in view. The selected item just disappears off screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you have the onkeyup and -down functions for us. That way I can make my answer more tailor made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the method [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). It is present on every element. Also you need to detect when an element is rendered off screen by getting the element's `offsetTop` and compare to the component's `offsetHeight`, when this number is higher then the component's `offsetHeight` you need to scroll it into view.

Comment: That definitely got me close. Unfortunately the react-infinite component doesn't act like a normal scroll. My `offsetHeight` for example, is 20. But my `offsetTop` is consistently in the hundreds. 

I'm still playing with `scrollIntoView`, though... It almost works. It's just really jumpy and inconsistent with the way that I have it set up right now.

`let elem = document.getElementById('selected')`
`elem.scrollIntoView({block: "start", behavior: "smooth"})`

Comment: Those things are difficult to set up correctly, but worthwhile if done properly. It takes a lot of trial and error.